# Como acceder a un elemento de un json

Tags: javascript

[image: a]

1. COMO PUEDO acceder al elemento [[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
   lo intento de la siguien forma pero no logro hacerlo correctamente:
   then.then[[PromiseStatus]]

Comment: daniel. Podrías cambiar la imagen por código por favor? Es más legible de esa forma. Además incluye tanto el mensaje de error que tienes en la consola y el código JS.

Comment: El tema es que no se como puedo capturar esa respuesta de la consola la cual es un json.

Comment: botón derecho guardar como/save as y luego limpias el log con un editor de textos para obtener la parte que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

No puedes Acceder a ese valor. Tiene que utilizar las funciones **resolved** y **reject** con alguna variable booleana que te indique en qué estado está.